# What's the `{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=bulkdomain` means in smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

I am reading a smarty project code, there is a `.tpl` file, and in it there is a form, its action is `{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=bulkdomain`:

```
<form method="post" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=bulkdomain">
...
```

what is this mean?

Does it means submit this request to the `.tpl`'s corresponding `.php` file?
but how about the `.php` file the function like?  because the php code is close sourced, I can not get it.

---

**EDIT-01**

I mean, in the template, use the `action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=bulkdomain"` for assigning the request method.

how about the request method should be in the template corresponding php file?

should it like this?

```
<?php

function bulkdomain($params)
{
    ...
}
```

---

**EDIT-02**

In the current running php file:

```
<?php

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/smartyHeader.php');
$smarty->registerPlugin('block' ,'hsp', 'test1');

$smarty->assign('foo', 'Foo');

$smarty->display('php/test.tpl');
```

if there submit the data, whether I will write the code in the php file like this?

```
<?php

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/smartyHeader.php');
$smarty->registerPlugin('block' ,'hsp', 'test1');

$smarty->assign('foo', 'Foo');

$smarty->display('php/test.tpl');

// accept the code
$action =$_GET['action']
```

whether I accept the action like upper writing code?

Comment: no need to delve into the source, there's a manual https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl

Comment: @Ghost Hi, friend, can you take a look at my edit-01?

Comment: on the receiving end of the form, just treat it like any normal get variable

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: since your form submission goes to the current php itself, just get the value of the get variable like any get variable, `$_GET['action']`, then you'll get `bulkdomain` in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$smarty.server.PHP_SELF` is the same as `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variable - means name of PHP file that currently running.

If you want to process you form which have `action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=bulkdomain"` you can just check if exists global `$_GET` variable with key "action" and value "bulkdomain", for example:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='bulkdomain') {
    // do smt
}
```

Comment: see my EDIT-02 brother.

Comment: @qg_java_17137 You should put the code **before** displaying the page (`$smarty->display('php/test.tpl');`) then you will be able to make a redirect with `header()` function, for example to prevent double sending of form.